# Long mysql query PHP

Tags: php, sql

Why does this not work?

It seems more logical to write a query this long on multiple lines, it would be a mess to write it on one line. It should be possible to do it like this?

Is it allowed to devide a long sql query into multiple lines like i do here:

Dont know why its not writing to the database, have checked all variables and names, it should be alright.

```
$vagtplanAdb = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO vagtplanA (ansatId, 
a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17,
a21, a22, a23, a24, a25, a26, a27,
a31, a32, a33, a34, a35, a36, a37,
a41, a42, a43, a44, a45, a46, a47,
a51, a52, a53, a54, a55, a56, a57,
a61, a62, a63, a64, a65, a66, a57,
a71, a72, a73, a74, a75, a76, a77,
a81, a82, a83, a84, a85, a86, a87,
a91, a92, a93, a94, a95, a96, a97,
a101, a102, a103, a104, a105, a106, a107,
a111, a112, a113, a114, a115, a116, a117,
a121, a122, a123, a124, a125, a126, a127) 
VALUES('$row_ansatId[id]',
'$_POST[a11]', '$_POST[a12]', '$_POST[a13]', '$_POST[a14]', '$_POST[a15]', '$_POST[a16]', '$_POST[a17]',
'$_POST[a21]', '$_POST[a22]', '$_POST[a23]', '$_POST[a24]', '$_POST[a25]', '$_POST[a26]', '$_POST[a27]',
'$_POST[a31]', '$_POST[a32]', '$_POST[a33]', '$_POST[a34]', '$_POST[a35]', '$_POST[a36]', '$_POST[a37]',
'$_POST[a41]', '$_POST[a42]', '$_POST[a43]', '$_POST[a44]', '$_POST[a45]', '$_POST[a46]', '$_POST[a47]',
'$_POST[a51]', '$_POST[a52]', '$_POST[a53]', '$_POST[a54]', '$_POST[a55]', '$_POST[a56]', '$_POST[a57]',
'$_POST[a61]', '$_POST[a62]', '$_POST[a63]', '$_POST[a64]', '$_POST[a65]', '$_POST[a66]', '$_POST[a67]',
'$_POST[a71]', '$_POST[a72]', '$_POST[a73]', '$_POST[a74]', '$_POST[a75]', '$_POST[a76]', '$_POST[a77]',
'$_POST[a81]', '$_POST[a82]', '$_POST[a83]', '$_POST[a84]', '$_POST[a85]', '$_POST[a86]', '$_POST[a87]',
'$_POST[a91]', '$_POST[a92]', '$_POST[a93]', '$_POST[a94]', '$_POST[a95]', '$_POST[a96]', '$_POST[a97]',
'$_POST[a101]', '$_POST[a102]', '$_POST[a103]', '$_POST[a104]', '$_POST[a105]', '$_POST[a106]', '$_POST[a107]',
'$_POST[a111]', '$_POST[a112]', '$_POST[a113]', '$_POST[a114]', '$_POST[a115]', '$_POST[a116]', '$_POST[a117]',
'$_POST[a121]', '$_POST[a122]', '$_POST[a123]', '$_POST[a124]', '$_POST[a125]', '$_POST[a126]', '$_POST[a127]') ") or die(mysql_error());
$vagtplanAdb->execute();
```

Comment: Given that you're as *wide open* to SQL injection as any code I've ever seen, technically this query could be doing *anything*.  Check for SQL errors to see why it's failing.  But more importantly, use prepared statements and query parameters to actually control what code you're executing.

Comment: `mysql_error()` will not return errors from mysqli or PDO. Use the correct error reporting.

Comment: `'$_POST[a12]'` should be `'".$_POST['a12']."'` or similar.

Comment: Gerald: what is the correct error reporting function to use?

Comment: This is not how prepared statements are meant to be used.

Comment: @JesperOlsen That depends if you are using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php).

Comment: It looks like you have 85 columns and 86 values. Use error reporting, provide the error, and we can help more. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php for how to use prepared statements.

Comment: @JesperOlsen above of what comments says, it is a very bad practice to have so many columns in your table, you need to re-design your database, otherwise it is hell to debugging. and you won't post directly in your database.

Comment: Its solved now, i restructured my data structure and split it up into more tables, much more convinient :)